# How Do I Set Drop Down Value Based On Another Drop Down In Share Point 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How do i set drop down value based on another drop down in share point 2010 ?

I have two drop downs in my share point list.One is hidden. I want to set the values for this drop down based on another drop down.
That is if the user select 'A' as value in first drop down , then value in the second drop down should automatically set to 'A'.
IM: I can use only out the box features here.

Comment: Are you using InfoPath forms may be [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7e53f58c-1c35-49b7-b1fc-b843ddefc917/creating-cascading-drop-down-boxes-in-sharepoint-2010-using-one-list) can help you to get ideas

Comment: Put your question here  [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)